# How to inject jquery (js) in Phantomjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, phantomjs

```js
var steps=[];
var testindex = 0;
var loadInProgress = false;//This is set to true when a page is still loading

var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36';
page.settings.javascriptEnabled = true;
page.settings.loadImages = false;//Script is much faster with this field set to false
phantom.cookiesEnabled = true;
phantom.javascriptEnabled = true;

console.log('All settings loaded, start with execution');
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};
steps = [

    function(){
        console.log('Step 1 - Open Fb home page');
        page.open("https://www.facebook.com/login.php", function(status){

        });
    },

    function(){
        console.log('Step 3 - Populate and submit the login form');
        page.evaluate(function(){
            document.getElementById("email").value="xxxx@gmail.com";
            document.getElementById("pass").value="xxx";
            document.getElementById("login_form").submit();
        });
    },
    function() {
        page.render('homepage.png');
    },
    function(){
      page.open("https://www.facebook.com/settings", function(status){

      });
    },
    function() {
        page.render('settings.png');
    },
];

interval = setInterval(executeRequestsStepByStep,50);

function executeRequestsStepByStep(){
    if (loadInProgress == false && typeof steps[testindex] == "function") {
        //console.log("step " + (testindex + 1));
        steps[testindex]();
        testindex++;
    }
    if (typeof steps[testindex] != "function") {
        console.log("test complete!");
        phantom.exit();
    }
}


page.onLoadStarted = function() {
    loadInProgress = true;
    console.log('Loading started');
};
page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    loadInProgress = false;
    console.log('Loading finished');
};
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};
```

How inject "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" and uses

```
$('#email').attr("value", "xxxx@gmail.com");

$('#pass').attr("value", "xxxx");

$('#login_form').submit();
```

I try all method, but script cant work.

Comment: I don't see where you tried to use jQuery in your code. Please [edit] your question to show the actual code. How do you know that it doesn't work? Have you waited for a certain amount of time? Have you taken screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke [includeJs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/inject-js.html) on your page object to do that and put your evaluate function inside the callback after injection with whatever JQuery code you want to execute.

Also, You will need to **remove the user agent at the start of the code**. It's presence prevents loading the external JQuery javascript. You'll also need to increase the time you pass to setInterval. 50 ms is not enough time for loading JQuery, manipulating the DOM and submitting the form. Something like 10 seconds sounds more practical to be on the safe side.

```
function(){
    console.log('Step 3 - Populate and submit the login form');
    page.includeJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js', function() {
      page.evaluate(function(){
        $('#email').attr("value", "xxxx@gmail.com");
        $('#pass').attr("value", "xxxx");
        $('#login_form').submit();
      });
    });



interval = setInterval(executeRequestsStepByStep, 10000);
```

Comment: If do like it 100% working, i know. Can u edit my code ?

Comment: I just re-edited the answer. I ran your code and tested after fixing all the above.. it works and is able to manipulate the DOM fields and submit. Of course after submitting, Facebook prevents you from continuing as cookies are disabled. However for the purpose of your question, this should fix it. Please revise and accept the answer when it's good on your end :) cheers!